# Using tikzcd in \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, tikz-cd, height

Earlier, I has asked to ask how to make `&`'s work for `tikzcd` environment nested inside `tabular`. I got my answer in `tikz-cd`'s manual---I just had to use `ampersand replacement=\&`.

Now, another problem has cropped up (in the same context):

The code:

```
\begin{tabular}{rc}
    First: & $1$\\
    \hline
    Second: & \multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            A\ar[r] \& B\ar[d]\\
            \& C
        \end{tikzcd}
    }\\
    \hline
    Third: & \\
    \hline
    Fourth: & $4$
\end{tabular}
```

generates

[image]

which is obviously not what is wanted.

Why is this happening? Is the vertical height of `tikzcd`'s output object being diminished?

How to fix this?

---

Observation:

It behaves weirdly only inside `\multirow`. That is, the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{rc}
    First: & $1$\\
    \hline
    Second: & \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
        A\ar[r] \& B\ar[d]\\
        \& C
    \end{tikzcd}\\
    \hline
    Third: & \\
    \hline
    Fourth: & $4$
\end{tabular}
```

produces, as expected,

[image]

But I want the second and third rows of the second column **merged** with the diagram being centered in that merged cell.

---

**The desired result:**

[image]

Comment: And then you look up `ampersand` in the `tikz-cd` manual, where it is explained what to do if you get this error.

Comment: Okay, so I encountered another problem, I will edit my post to include that.

Comment: Please extend your examples to complete documents, that makes it easier for others to copy and test.

Comment: You would need to put some empty rows after the `tikzcd` to make space for it. Or at least rows with empty cells in the second column.

Comment: But actually, it would be more logical to put `Second:` in a `\multirow` and not the `tikzcd` in your example.

Comment: I have changed to solution. No `\multirow` necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rc}
    First: & $1$\\
    \hline
    \makecell[cr]{Second:\\Third:} & \makecell{%
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            A\ar[r] \& B\ar[d]\\
            \& C
        \end{tikzcd}}\\
      \hline
    Fourth: & $4$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I meant second and third column of the second row to be merged. Apologies for the confusion. Editing it.

Comment: You have only two columns. Maybe you should add a sketch of the desired result.

Comment: yea, I interchanged the 'column' and 'row' above. I created a lot of confusion, and I sincerely apologize for that. Your most recent answer address this. Just one thing: Can you get the `Second:` and `Third:` stick together close to each other (skipping a space of row between them; that's why I used `\multirow`)? I will attach a sketch of the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for persisting with me! You saved the day(s)!

Answer (score 1):

You get more precise alignment *without* `multirow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rc}
  First: & $1$\\
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}} Second: \\ Third: \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A\ar[r] & B\ar[d]\\
            & C
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{tabular}
  \\
  \hline
  Fourth: & $4$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Do you see the trick? Nesting `tabular`.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen this use of nested `tabular`s before. Thanks!

Comment: In fact that is what `\makecell` does. Makecell is just a higher abstraction level.

Answer (score 0):

With `tabularray` package and in `tikzcd` image use of ampersand replacement `\&`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{colspec={rc},
                 vspan=even
                 }
First:  &    1              \\  \hline
Second: & \SetCell[r=2]{c}  % <--- tabularray syntax for multi row cell 
            \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            A \rar  \& B \dar   \\
                    \& C
            \end{tikzcd}    \\
Third:  &                   \\  \hline
Fourth: &   4 
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
From your edited question follows, that you not need `multirow` cell, but text in the cell adjacent to cell with image with text in two lines. This is simple achieved by use of `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[r,m]Q[c,m]}}
First:  &    1              \\  \hline
{Second:\\ Third:}
        &   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            A \rar  \& B \dar   \\
                    \& C
            \end{tikzcd}    \\  \hline
Fourth: &   4
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]